# Where did all the questions go?

Tags: bug

Visiting https://stackoverflow.com/questions shows that there have never been any questions asked, where have they gone?
[image]

Comment: Caching blues, it'll sort itself out soon enough.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Uhm...? wrong dupe?

Comment: ... and for what it's just worth, I got exactly the same issue on Meta around the same time... but likewise; "all sorted now".

Comment: @Matt: No, that's the same underlying problem. The caching servers are haywire, so all the pages that rely on memory-cached data are acting up. Including the web sockets, so questions show up as new when they are not, or not show up at all.

Comment: That other question was from an hour ago, and my issue started a few minutes ago.

Comment: @Matt rread the dup, there's a lot of craziness and probably all rlated

Comment: @Matt: no, it is still happening on certain servers, it takes a while to propagate throughout the cluster.